# How much time did it take Yuu Otosaka to fulfill his promise to Tomori?

Tags: charlotte

I just finished watching Charlotte and I'm curious as to whether it is mentioned anywhere how much time it took him to fulfill his promise?

Comment: Judging by the fact that he was high school first year at the beginning of his journey and Tomori still wearing school uniform in the last episode, it tool him 1-2 years max.

Comment: @AstralSea Oh yeah. I only noticed Ayumi's uniform, and hence was afraid that the time period could have been as long as 3 years. Thankfully, it isn't :D. Was the exact duration mentioned anywhere?

Comment: No, it was not, re-watched the episode and did not hear anything about it.

Comment: I see. Thanks ;_;. If I'm not wrong, Charlotte isn't even adapted from any manga/novel, right?

Comment: Charlotte is Anime original, there is a manga adapation being made and an OVA coming out in March. However, there's currently not an answer to your question. We know they lose powers at age 20, and we know that he left soon after his [16th birthday](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vDuSU.jpg) so there was plenty of time that could have passed but as @AstralSea said the upper limit is their graduation date.

Comment: Actually it a little bit more than an year, before he turned 18 and lost his power, Tomori still have her uniform when he is back so yea.

Comment: They lose powers when they turn 20.

Comment: One year iirc. I don't recall the proof, but it is around a year.

Answer (score 1):

He lost his powers after using them multiple times per rotation. So, keeping in mind he made travel back-and-forth multiple times, and to keep increasing his profits, it might have taken more than 2 years without the powers if we take into account the time he spent traveling. But based on his promise, it only took him around 2 years to increase profits and start the school.

Answer (score 1):

Two years. He was 16 when he left and he had time until before he was 18, because he would lose the powers then.

Comment: If he was 16 when he left, and he got back before he turned 16, wouldn't it have taken him *less than* two years? Specifically, it could have taken him any amount of time between one day and 1.99 years.